# Союзное или бессоюзное предложение?

Tags: синтаксис

Подскажите, пожалуйста, предложения типа: *"Но захоти: **так** был бы деловой"* (Гриб.), *"Позови обедать, — **так** пешком прибегут!..*" — союзные или бессоюзные?

В одних источниках говорится, что в бессоюзных предложениях могут использоваться частицы, в частности, частица *так*.
Но в то же время слово "так" может быть и союзом; например, на *Грамоте.ру*:
III. союз. 1. Вследствие этого, потому, в связи с этим.
(*Хочешь хорошо учиться, **так** старайся. У меня гости, **так** я ими и занимаюсь. Зрение слабеет, **так** приходится надевать очки.*)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Прежде всего, надо иметь в виду, что единой точки зрения тут пока не выработано. дело в том, что частица - довольно своеобразная часть речи, она может "маскироваться" под многие другие грамматические объекты, выступая то в роли союза, то в роли наречия, то вообще в роли суффикса (в неопределенных местоимения типа кто-то). Общего подхода пока не выработано. Поэтому разночтения в источниках вполне возможны.

> В одних источниках говорится, что в бессоюзных предложениях могут
>   использоваться частицы, в частности, частица так. Но в то же время
>   слово "так" может быть и союзом, например, на Грамоте ру: III. союз.
>   1. Вследствие этого, потому, в связи с этим.

Совершенно верно, "так" может быть и частицей, и союзом. И еще наречием и вводным словом. Зависит от контекста, иногда от авторского понимания. Надо смотреть на функцию.

> "Но захоти: так был бы деловой" (Гриб.),

Здесь "так" придает тексту выразительность, но при этом спокойно изымается из текста тез нарушения смысла и грамматики. Следовательно, здесь частица, скорее всего - усилительная.

> "Позови обедать, — так пешком прибегут!.."

А здесь картина, на мой взгляд, иная. Первая и вторая часть представляет собой причину (условие) и следствие (условное действие). Тут воля автора решать, чем будет "так". Пунктуация, к сожалению, XIX века (сейчас бы бессоюзное с тире без запятой писали), поэтому последить наверняка не возможно, но судя по восклицательному знаку это именно бессоюзное, а так - усилительная частица.

> например, на Грамоте ру: III. союз. 1. Вследствие этого, потому, в
>   связи с этим. Хочешь хорошо учиться, так старайся. У меня гости, так я
>   ими и занимаюсь. Зрение слабеет, так приходится надевать очки.

А здесь всё понятно. "Так" выводит следствие, Если убрать это "так" придется ставить двоеточие вместо запятой. Здесь так - союз.

Comment: Единственным союзом  для придаточных следствия считается союз ТАК ЧТО.

Comment: @Sibylla В чем состоит ваш вопрос ко мне? Я не могу комментировать ваше заявление, оно не относится к моему ответу. Я про "придаточные следствия" вообще ничего не говорил.

Comment: Зрение слабеет, так что приходится надевать очки. Это СПП с придаточным следствия, союз ТАК ЧТО. Зрение слабеет, так  приходится надевать очки. Это БСП, так - частица, а не союз.

Comment: @Sibylia, формулируйте, пожалуйста, ваши замечания к моему ответу на содержательном уровне. Если у вас есть вопросы про очки, можете задать в отдельной теме. А здесь, пожалуйста, конкретно. Какое положение в моем ответе вам не понравилось? Я не разбирал предложений с очками и не рассматривал СПП вовсе.

Comment: Формулирую: ТАК - это частица, союзом может быть, если входит в составной союз ЕСЛИ....ТАК.

Comment: @Sibylla Ну так я не согласен с Вами. Смотрите цитату "Грамоты". Там нет указания, что "так" - союз. Аналогично - в всех доступных словарях. Более того, я начал ответ с того, что мнения единого нет. Но вы считаете, что правильный - только ваш источник, специализированный и малоизвестный.

Answer (score 2):

В "Синтаксисе современного русского языка" рассматриваются такие модели в теме "**Бессоюзное предложение с условно-следственным и условным значением**". Пунктуация — запятая или тире (при наличии паузы).

Частица ТАК в этом случае считается **структурным элементом**, поясняющим отношение между частями БСП:  Заварил кашу, **так** не жалей масла. Хочешь есть калачи, **так** не сиди  на печи. Пообещали — **так** надо делать.

Отметим, что при наличии частицы ТАК в БСП может ставиться **запятая**, в то время как при её отсутствии ставилось бы тире:  Заварил кашу — не жалей масла.

Частицы ТАК и ТО могут **входить составной союз** ЕСЛИ...ТО, ЕСЛИ...ТАК, в этом случае предложение является сложноподчиненным: **Если** хочешь есть калачи, **так** не сиди на печи.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60303/discussion-on-answer-by-sibylla----).